# Dynamic Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Is it possible to have a Viewpager that knows what the current, next and previous page is and when I swipe either way the state changes so there always will be max 3 pages?

Hope you get the point

Comment: The default view pager behavior is the what you want, I didn't get the dynamic part

Comment: Well, I suppose that if you have a PageAdapter which has 5 static pages that is a static behaviour. What I want is to _dynamically_ load a new page each time I swipe, but I suppose the ViewPager needs to know the previous and the next to be able to make the transition.

Comment: `PagerAdapter` is already based on a dynamic model - `ViewPager` loads the pages it want from it dynamically. It keeps one off-screen page on either side preloaded by default, and this can be configured via the `setOffscreenPageLimit()` method.

Comment: I'm still confused because in all tutorials I find there is always a static list of fragments. And in `PagerAdapter`, `instantiateItem`wants a position argument

Answer (score 0):

ViewPager has the [OnPageListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). the `onPageSelected` gives you the position of the current page selected